# How did Thomson come with his "Plum Pudding" Model?

Tags: atomic-physics, history, atoms

- Why couldn't he not think of something like a triangular or any distorted shaped atom (and why only a spherical one)?
- Can't the positive charge be in some other fashion which is not evenly distributed?
- Can't it be that positive protons are present in a sea of negatively charged electrons?

Comment: You'd have to ask Thomson. You would probably be better off asking this on the [History of Science SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) since it isn't a physics question.

Comment: @Divyanshu He was a physicist. If you're a physicist, absent evidence otherwise, everything is a sphere or a plane or a straight line.

Answer (score 4):

The honest reasoning in favor of the so-called "plum pudding" model is available in a number of public-domain sources from that time period. You might enjoy the 1914 article [*The Structure of the Atom*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MxJLAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA586&dq=thomson+structure+atom&hl=xx-elmer&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ9tbiivHWAhVDzoMKHewVALEQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=thomson%20structure%20atom&f=false) in Nature No. 2308.

It was known at the time that corpuscles of negative charge (now called "electrons") could be extracted from an atom, leaving a positively-charged particle (now called an "ion") of approximately the same mass as the neutral. Both the neutral and its ion, if they had a shape at all, must have been spherical in shape, since they showed no angular dependence in interactions with other particles. No fundamental corpuscle of positive charge could be extracted from a neutral. Therefore, the reasoning goes, the atom must consist of its "electrons" as well as a heavy positively-charged part. What's more, since positive and negative charges attract one another, these charges must pull themselves into a compressed, isotropic volume. The simplest model (for we do so love simplicity) then has the electrons distributed throughout a positively-charged sphere.